# How to overcome slow page loading?

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I was trying to import a huge amount of data from one database to another. I successfully imported all my data from one table to another. Now I am trying to display all those data into a gridview. But the problem is that now my page is loading very slowly and the major problem is that in the first page load there is no data shown in the gridview, so I have to again refresh the page to display the data. Please guide my that how can I overcome with this problem. I heard about gzip application from one of my friend. Please tell me more about it. Thank You!

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    adsource = new PagedDataSource();
    adsource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    adsource.PageSize = 20;
    adsource.AllowPaging = true;
    adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
    btnfirst.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
    btnprevious.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
    btnlast.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
    btnnext.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
    GridView1.DataSource = adsource; GridView1.DataBind();
    s=Convert.ToInt32(this.ViewState["vs"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Pagination could be a good start.

Comment: How does your code to load the data into the grid look? Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @Asken: I am calling a function show() within page load.

Comment: @Asken within show() I am using a data table object to return the query result.and then within if statement I have specified this code-
`if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{adsource = new PagedDataSource();
adsource.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
adsource.PageSize = 20;
adsource.AllowPaging = true;
adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
btnfirst.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
btnprevious.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
btnlast.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
btnnext.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
GridView1.DataSource = adsource;
GridView1.DataBind();
s=Convert.ToInt32(this.ViewState["vs"].ToString());}`

Comment: I've added your code to the question but you should provide something that is easily testable for the responders. Check out how to ask good questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking